# Is there a generic method to find out if network data is sent encrypted?

Tags: security, winapi, encryption, network-programming, exploit

I am working on a penetration testing framework for computer games that will detect potential security vulnerabilities.
Part of the automated testing will be to verify that the network data is sent encrypted.

One approach would be to hook the Windows socket and encryption functions of the game and determine a connection between encryption and network packets based on the frequency of function calls.

Another approach would be to store the encrypted data and then check whether it is passed on to socket functions.

Are the approaches reasonable, or are there already better ways to accomplish this task?

Comment: You could buffer a significant amount of traffic (~512kb?) and perform frequency analysis.  If the data is encrypted, we would expect the standard deviation to be quite small.